# DevExtreme Scheduler Tooltip Resize on click

Tags: angular, tooltip, scheduler, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I currently working with the DevExtreme Scheduler Widget and want to resize the Appointment Tooltip after a user clicks on a div inside the tooltip. At the moment i have the following code:

```
<div *dxTemplate=„let appointment of ‚appointment-tooltip‘“> 
    <div (click)=„furtherInformation = !furtherInformation“> + </div>
    <div *ngIf=„furtherInformation“> .... </div>
</div>
```

The content is displayed, but the height and width of the tooltip are not updated.

Can somebody help me or show me the right direction to solve my problem?